# Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.security.Encrypt

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am trying to encrypt a database password for my `Java EE Application` in the terminal. according to this [tutorial](http://www.techpaste.com/2013/09/steps-encrypt-clear-text-passwords-weblogic-server/)

The steps are as follows:

1. Change directory to your domain’s bin folder (For Eg. cd WLS_home\user_projects\domains\mydomain\bin)
2. Use `setDomainEnv.cmd/sh` script to setup the environment
3. Run `java weblogic.security.Encrypt` which will prompt for the password and will print the encrypted value in stdout.

However, when I execute 'java weblogic.security.Encrypt', I am presented with the following:

> Error: Could not find or load main class weblogic.security.Encrypt

I am developing my project in Eclipse and have configured my `Weblogic-12.1.3` server in Eclipse. I am not sure why this error is happening, but I expect its because my java version is 1.8, and maybe it expects me to use java 1.6 which I think comes with Weblogic installation.

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Have you tried changing your java version? Is there actually a `static void main(String args[]) method in Encrypt`? Could you post the code?

Comment: @LanguidSquid I am not sure where this code is stored. I can look around the WebLogic directories for it. I think I can try to use the java version that it looks like came with the installation.

Answer (score 19):

You must type
`cd WLS_home/user_projects/domains/mydomain/bin/`

`. ./setDomainEnv.sh`

You must use two separate dots, that should do the trick!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Brilliant, been trying the steps provided by the ORACLE documentation, 

This worked fine!

Comment: Can I just check why is there a need for 2 seperate dots?

Comment: Thank you it worked. But any idea why do we need that dot?

Comment: @Manish  '.' is to source the script.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Java 8 with WebLogic 12.1.3 on Linux. I had to add some classpath entries, but it worked like this:

```
java -cp /home/devuser/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/modules/features/*:/home/devuser/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/modules/*  weblogic.security.Encrypt
```

Comment: it still can't find that class :/

Comment: Are you on Linux or Windows? The classpath syntax is a bit different on Windows. Use ; instead of : to delimit the two directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I set `set enableHotswapFlag=` to true. please leave this flag empty and try.