# unable to build and deploy socket transport for Oracle Service bus in weblogic?

Tags: java, ant, weblogic11g, oracle-service-bus, oracle-enterprise-linux

I am following the link https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/dev.1111/e15866/example.htm#OSBDV1445 to build and deploy socket transport. 
The Issue is that when I am going to run command ant deploy it is giving following error
Buildfile: build.xml 
BUILD FAILED 
/u01/app/oracle/fmw/Oracle_OSB1/samples/servicebus/sample-transport/build.xml:7: taskdef class weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy cannot be found

kindly help.

Thanks.

Comment: Issue has been resolved by adding following tags in build.xml  <taskdef name="wldeploy" classname="weblogic.ant.taskdefs.management.WLDeploy">

<classpath>

<pathelement location="${weblogic.home}\server\lib\weblogic.jar"/>

</classpath>

</taskdef>

Comment: and we are running [./setDomainEnv.sh] , it is not running.  It is running only by double dot as [. ./setDomainEnv.sh] from putty reference is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943752/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-weblogic-security-encrypt